# React sortable js is removing bootstrap grid style

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-sortablejs

I am building a simple react app and I am trying to implement [React Sortable Js](https://github.com/SortableJS/react-sortablejs) to my bootstrap grid style. But When I wrap  with `<ReactSortable>` then grid doesn't remain two boxes side by side in two row but it becomes one box in one line in four rows.

**CodeSandBox** :- [My React App Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-sanne-cjmwy0?file=/src/App.js)

App.js

```
function Card({ item }) {

  return (
    <div>
      <Col
        sm
        className="grid-view lrg-view"
      >
        <h5 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>{item.name}</h5>
        <hr />
      </Col>
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  const [thirdGroup, setThirdGroup] = useState([
    { name: "Box 1", id: "1" },
    { name: "Box 2", id: "2" },
    { name: "Box 3", id: "3" },
    { name: "Box 4", id: "4" }
  ]);

  return (
    <Container>
      <Row>
        <ReactSortable
          list={thirdGroup}
          setList={setThirdGroup}
          animation={250}
        >
          {thirdGroup.map((item) => (
            <Card key={item.id} item={item} />
          ))}
        </ReactSortable>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  )
```

I have also tried by putting `Row` inside `ReactSortable` then It is showing grid but not sorting.

I am trying for hours and looked into many issues but it is still not working.

**What I am trying to do**

I am trying to put two boxes side by side in one row and then same for the second row. Like [Grid Row in Bootstrap](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-alex-eskwvc?file=/public/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems in your snippet.

- The `react-bootstrap` `Col` component is required to be a direct child of the `Row` component for the grid layout to work. Since the direct child of the `Row` component in your snippet is the `ReactSortable` component, then it doesn't satisfy this requirement.
- Your `Card` component should be the `Col` component instead of a `div`. This satisfies the requirement mentioned above.

To resolve the problem, we need the `ReactSortable` component to act as a `Row` component, using the `tag` property. You may refer to this part of the [documentation for more info](https://github.com/SortableJS/react-sortablejs#custom-component).

A working [example on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-fast-xphy9w?file=/src/App.js):

```
import "./styles.css";
import { ReactSortable } from "react-sortablejs";
import { useState } from "react";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import Row from "react-bootstrap/Row";
import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col";

function Card({ item }) {
  let backgroundColor = "#dad9f3";

  return (
    <Col
      sm
      className="grid-view lrg-view"
      style={Object.assign({}, { backgroundColor })}
    >
      <h5 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>{item.name}</h5>
      <hr />
    </Col>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [thirdGroup, setThirdGroup] = useState([
    { name: "Box 1", id: "1" },
    { name: "Box 2", id: "2" },
    { name: "Box 3", id: "3" },
    { name: "Box 4", id: "4" }
  ]);

  return (
    <Container>
      <ReactSortable
        tag={Row}
        list={thirdGroup}
        setList={setThirdGroup}
        animation={250}
      >
        {thirdGroup.map((item) => (
          <Card key={item.id} item={item} />
        ))}
      </ReactSortable>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, It was really helpful. And It worked But I also want to add `<div className="col-1"></div>` between every `Col` to add a little margin between the `Col`s so they don't attach to each other and When I `wrap` `Card` with `<span></span>` then It doesn't work as `row`

Comment: And Also they aren't showing two in one row and two in another

Comment: You can simply use the column specifiers in the `Col` component, in this case, `sm={6}` since bootstrap has a `12` column max default. Kindly up-vote my answer as well, if it helped you, thanks.